# CMake depend on "all" target from custom target

Tags: dependencies, cmake

I'm making a library that needs to be packaged in a fancy way, and as part of that, I have a script that contains these lines:

```
#only install the lib component, nd put in the a special directory
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(o_destdir_install
  COMMAND DESTDIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/o_package ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCOMPONENT=lib -P cmake_install.cmake
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake
  COMMENT "Building o_package directory with DESTDIR"
  )
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(o_destdir_install all preinstall)
```

I've found this code from the old UseDebian.cmake dpkg builder, however it does NOT build all and preinstall before it runs the install. Making my target depend on a non-built-in target seems to work, but I can't depend on any built-in targets it seems. How can I get this to work?

Also it would be nice if I could depend on a single component install preferably without the hacking calling of cmake, but I'm fine either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hacking together your own install target, you should just piggy-back on the existing one using the `install(CODE)` form:

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND DESTDIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/o_package ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCOMPONENT=lib -P cmake_install.cmake")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_custom_target(my_deploy
    DEPENDS all
    # Add your commands...
)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can depend on 'all' target using `ALL` keyword. See [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target).

Comment: I think that it makes ALL depend on the custom target, and not the reverse.

Comment: Probably. I'm not native English speaker, so "except/expect" and "depend on" are giving me hard times.