# dependency on default CMake target

Tags: makefile, cmake, dependencies

**TL;DR**

How do I add a CMake dependency on the default build target (`all`)?

**Long version**

I have a project that consists of a number of libraries and executables which should always be built. Additionally, there is a handful of small optional executables. I added a custom target `extended-all` with dependencies on the optional executables. Now I would like `extended-all` to depend on the default build target (whence the name `extended-all`!), so that everything gets built if `make extended-all` is invoked. As things stand now, CMake only builds the direct dependencies of the optional executables.

Is it possible to achieve this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875854/cmake-depend-on-all-target-from-custom-target) is similar in spirit, but the answer does not apply to my case.

Comment: That request has been out there for a while (see also e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073614/how-to-add-dependency-in-cmake-targets)). You could add your support to the corresponding CMake feature request: [Issue #8438: add_dependencies() for "build-in cmake targets"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/8438).

Comment: @Florian thanks. Support added.